# No IOException on Outputstream when dataconnection lost

Tags: android, post, timeout, httpurlconnection, 3g

I'm developing this android application which basically uploads images to a webservice.
I have a asynctask where I send the file to the server, using this code:

```
protected Boolean doInBackground(byte[]... params) {
     HttpURLConnection connection = getConnection();
     BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream()); 
     Log.d("OutputStream", "stream created, about to write");
     out.write(params[0]);
     Log.d("OutputStream", "all bytes written");
     out.close();
}
```

Of course, this block of code is wrapped within a try catch, catching IOExceptions etc. 
The problem is that when I interrupt the connection **after** I see the first logtext, an exception is never thrown or only after a really long time (talking about 20 minutes or so), which doesn't make any sense at all.

The HttpURLConnection is set up like this:

```
urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");         
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", this.contentType);
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", String.format("custom-user-agent/%d", R.integer.version_code));
urlConnection.addRequestProperty("SessionID", this.sessionID);
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(30000);
urlConnection.setReadTimeout(30000);
urlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
urlConnection.connect();
```

Funny thing is, this only happens when interrupting a EDGE/3G connection. When I interrupt a wifi connection, the exception is thrown immediately (which, of course,  is a lot more convenient).

Any idea on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A while ago, we've encountered this problem also, but only on a Samsung Galaxy SII with Android 2.3.4. All other devices did not have this issue. There is no way to program around this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need use urlConnection.connect(): the connection is open implicity when yo do the .getOutputStream().
Also, if you make the .connect(), you can't make it before at the .getOutputStream().
In addition, you must set the Content-Type header:

```
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Comment: The content-type is set to "application/octet-stream". But do the headers actually matter when a connection is interrupted? I will remove the .connect() though, thanks.

Comment: Ok, I haven't not realize that you already set the Content-Type. Anyway, I don't think the headers matter in this issue, like you says. It works now?